# If $\gcd (a,b)=1$ and $c\mid a+b$, then $\gcd (a,c)=\gcd(b,c)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\gcd (a,b)=1$ and $c\mid a+b$, then $\gcd (a,c)=\gcd(b,c)=1$

so far I have:
$ax+by=1$

$(a+b)/c=q$ for some integer $q$ so $a+b=cq$

$au+cv=1$

$bl+ck=1$

$au+cv=bl+ck$

Where should I go from here? step by step explanation please!

Comment: The claim is quite difficult to parse as it's written.  Is this what you mean?  "If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ and $c \mid (a + b)$, then $\gcd(a, c) = \gcd(b, c) = 1$."

Comment: yeah you are correct

Answer (score 4):

A Bezout argument can be pushed through, but I think the following argument is more natural.

Suppose to the contrary that $\gcd(a,c)\gt 1$. Then there exists $d\gt 1$ that divides $a$ and $c$. Since $a+b=cq$ for some $q$, we have $b=cq-a$. Since $d$ divides $c$ and $a$, we have $d$ divides $b$, contradicting the fact that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score 2):

As you've started, using Bezout's Lemma we have:

$$ax + by = 1$$

has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}$. Now from the condition we have: $a + b = cq \implies b = cq - a$. Substituting we have:

$$ax + (cq - a)y = 1$$
$$a(x-y) + c(qy) = 1$$

Since $x+y$ and $qy$ are integers $gcd(a,c) = 1$. Simularly we get $gcd(b,c) = 1$

Comment: Should it be $a(x-y)$ instead of $a(x+y)$? Does the proof still work?

Comment: @Nighty Thanks for spotting the error. It should be $x-y$ instead of $x+y$. The proof works regardless as we need the factor of in front of $a$ to be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ a\,$ is coprime to $\,a+b\,$ since $\,(a,a+b) = (a,b) = 1,\ $ using $\ (a,n) = (a,\,n\ {\rm mod}\ a).\,$
Thus  $\ a\,$ is coprime to every factor of $\,a+b,\,$ including $\,c.\,$ Ditto for $\,b\,$ by $\, a\leftrightarrow b\,$ symmetry.